# Keyed Collection in Python?

Tags: python, keyedcollection

Is there any equivalent to [KeyedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx) in Python, i.e. a set where the elements have (or dynamically generate) their own keys?

i.e. the goal here is to **avoid storing the key in two places**, and therefore dictionaries are less than ideal (hence the question).

Comment: Could you say more about why you don't want to have keys and values?  Python will generally just reference the same object as a key and a value, so you aren't incurring twice the memory.

Comment: @Ned: Because semantically, it doesn't make as much sense. When an object *knows* its key, it doesn't make sense to put it in a dictionary -- it's *not* a key-value pair. It's more of a semantic issue than anything else. (There's also the issue that `KeyedCollection` can be **indexed** by an ordinal as well, but I don't need that here specifically. It's useful in other situations, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mehrdad said:

> Because semantically, it doesn't make as much sense. When an object
>   knows its key, it doesn't make sense to put it in a dictionary -- it's
>   not a key-value pair. It's more of a semantic issue than anything
>   else.

With this constraint, there is nothing in Python that does what you want.  I suggest you use a dict and not worry about this level of detail on the semantics.  @Gabi Purcaru's answer shows how you can create an object with the interface you want.  Why get bothered about how it's working internally?

It could be that C#'s KeyedCollection is doing the same thing under the covers: asking the object for its key and then storing the key for fast access. In fact, from the docs:

> By default, the KeyedCollection(Of TKey, TItem) includes a lookup
>   dictionary that you can obtain with the Dictionary property. When an
>   item is added to the KeyedCollection(Of TKey, TItem), the item's key
>   is extracted once and saved in the lookup dictionary for faster
>   searches. This behavior is overridden by specifying a dictionary
>   creation threshold when you create the KeyedCollection(Of TKey,
>   TItem). The lookup dictionary is created the first time the number of
>   elements exceeds that threshold. If you specify –1 as the threshold,
>   the lookup dictionary is never created.

Comment: It does, but (1) it can be disabled, and (2) it still allows access by ordinal.

Comment: @Mehrdad: make up your mind.  You said you didn't care about access by ordinal.

Comment: I said don't care about it for **this** case, but I do care about it in general (i.e. most other times when I need a KeyedCollection). But notice point (1) as well.

Comment: OK, well, we're building up a Python implementation of KeyedCollection, we can add in indexed lookup too, but keep in mind: that will require storing another reference to the value.

Answer (score 4):

You can simulate that very easily:

```
class KeyedObject(object):
    def get_key(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("You must subclass this before you can use it.")

class KeyedDict(dict):
    def append(self, obj):
        self[obj.get_key()] = obj
```

Now you can use a `KeyedDict` instead of `dict` with subclasses of `KeyedObject` (where `get_key` return a valid key based on some object property).

Comment: @Mehrdad: this doesn't store the key twice, it stores two *references* to the key.  If you have a large string as a key, the string only exists in memory once.

Comment: @Ned: Yeah I know it's storing a reference, but it's storing the reference twice. Not only do I not like duplication, but more importantly, see my comment on your other comment.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Memory is usually plentiful (until it's not). Which would your users prefer: a program that works quickly because it uses data structures appropriate to the task at hand, or a program that works less quickly but doesn't have unnecessary duplication in its internal data structures?

Comment: @kindall: It's not a memory issue -- it's a readability and semantics issue. If I have to store something twice, then I have to keep track of it twice, and that gets that much harder to read. Being worried about memory here is a bit overkill; that's not a concern.

Answer (score 2):

Given your constraints, everyone trying to implement what you're looking for using a `dict` is barking up the wrong tree. Instead, you should write a `list` subclass that overrides `__getitem__` to provide the behavior you want. I've written it so it tries to get the desired item by index first, then falls back to searching for the item by the `key` attribute of the contained objects. (This could be a property if the object needs to determine this dynamically.)

There's no way to avoid a linear search if you don't want to duplicate something somewhere; I am sure the C# implementation does exactly the same thing if you don't allow it to use a dictionary to store the keys.

```
class KeyedCollection(list):
     def __getitem__(self, key):
         if isinstance(key, int) or isinstance(key, slice):
             return list.__getitem__(key)
         for item in self:
             if getattr(item, "key", 0) == key:
                 return item
         raise KeyError('item with key `%s` not found' % key)
```

You would probably also want to override `__contains__` in a similar manner so you could say `if "key" in kc...`. If you want to make it even more like a `dict`, you could also implement `keys()` and so on. They will be equally inefficient, but you will have an API like a `dict`, that also works like a list.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Though I could implement it by hand, I was wondering if there's something built-in so that I wouldn't have to define/include the class in every project I need it for. But anyway, this is definitely a solution; +1 for the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not much of a C#'er, but I think dictionaries is what you need.

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Or maybe lists:

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use a `dict`?  If the key already exists, a reference to the key will be used in the dict; it won't be senselessly duplicated.

```
class MyExample(object):
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value

m = MyExample("foo", "bar")
d = {}

d[m.key] = m

first_key = d.keys()[0]
first_key is m.key  # returns True
```

If the key doesn't already exist, a copy of it will be saved, but I don't see that as a problem.

```
def lame_hash(s):
    h = 0
    for ch in s:
        h ^= ord(ch)
    return h

d = {}
d[lame_hash(m.key)] = m
print d  # key value is 102 which is stored in the dict

lame_hash(m.key) in d  # returns True
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you meant, but this dictionary will create it's own keys as you add to it...

```
class KeyedCollection(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.current_key = 0
    def add(self, item):
        self[self.current_key] = item

abc = KeyedCollection()
abc.add('bob')
abc.add('jane')
>>> abc
{0: 'bob', 1: 'jane'}
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid storing the key twice, which this doesn't do. :\

Answer (score 0):

How about a `set()`? The elements can have their own k

Answer (score 0):

To go a little more in detail that the already correct answer from @Gabi Purcaru's answer, here a class that do the same as gabi one's but that also check for correct given type on key and value (as the TKey and TValue of the .net KeyedCollection).

```
class KeyedCollection(MutableMapping):
    """
    Provides the abstract base class for a collection (:class:`MutableMappinp`) whose keys are embedded in the values.
    """
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
    _dict = None  # type: dict

    def __init__(self, seq={}):
        self._dict = dict(seq)

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __is_type_key_correct__(self, key):
        """
        Returns: The type of keys in the collection
        """
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __is_type_value_correct__(self, value):
        """
        Returns: The type of values in the collection
        """
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_key_for_item(self, value):
        """
        When implemented in a derivated class, extracts the key from the specified element.
        Args:
            value: the element from which to extract the key (of type specified by :meth:`type_value`)

        Returns: The key of specified element (of type specified by :meth:`type_key`)
        """
        pass

    def __assert_type_key(self, key, arg_name='key'):
        if not self.__is_type_key_correct__(key) :
            raise ValueError("{} type is not correct".format(arg_name))

    def __assert_type_value(self, value, arg_name='value'):
        if not self.__is_type_value_correct__(value) :
            raise ValueError("{} type is not correct".format(arg_name))

    def add(self, value):
        """
        Adds an object to the KeyedCollection.
        Args:
            value: The object to be added to the KeyedCollection (of type specified by :meth:`type_value`).
        """
        key = self.get_key_for_item(value)
        self._dict[key] = value

    # Implements abstract method __setitem__ from MutableMapping parent class
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.__assert_type_key(key)
        self.__assert_type_value(value)
        if value.get_key() != key:
            raise ValueError("provided key does not correspond to the given KeyedObject value")
        self._dict[key] = value

    # Implements abstract method __delitem__ from MutableMapping parent class
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self.__assert_type_key(key)
        self._dict.pop(key)

    # Implements abstract method __getitem__ from MutableMapping parent class (Mapping base class)
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        self.__assert_type_key(key)
        return self._dict[key]

    # Implements abstract method __len__ from MutableMapping parent class (Sized mixin on Mapping base class)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._dict)

    # Implements abstract method __iter__ from MutableMapping parent class (Iterable mixin on Mapping base class)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._dict)
        pass

    # Implements abstract method __contains__ from MutableMapping parent class (Container mixin on Mapping base class)
    def __contains__(self, x):
        self.__assert_type_key(x, 'x')
        return x in self._dict
```